# How to close a Drawer from another React Component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to close my EventDetailsDrawer from the HomePageContent Component. In the EventDetailsDrawer Component, there is a callback function `onClose()`. When the Drawer is opening, i can use the `onClose()` Function to close the drawer by clicking anywhere outside the drawer. How can i use these function in my HomePageContent Component?

I use [the Drawer from ant.design](https://ant.design/components/drawer/).
Here are my to Components:

**The HomePageContent:**

```
class HomePageContent extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showDrawer: false,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        showDrawer: !this.state.showDrawer
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CreateEventButton></CreateEventButton>
            <br />
            <List
                grid={{ gutter: 16, xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3, lg: 3, xl: 4, xxl: 4 }}
                dataSource={data}
                renderItem={item => (
                    <List.Item>
                        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <EventCard 
                            title={item.title}
                            descp={item.description}
                            date={item.date}
                            location={item.location}
                            owner={item.owner}
                        >
                        </EventCard>
                        </div>
                        <EventDetailsDrawer 
                            showDrawer={this.state.showDrawer}
                            title = {item.title}
                        >
                        </EventDetailsDrawer>
                    </List.Item>
                )}
            />
            <EventDetailsDrawer showDrawer={this.state.showDrawer}></EventDetailsDrawer>
        </div>
    );
 }

}

export default HomePageContent
```

**EventDetailsDrawer**

```
class EventDetailsDrawer extends Component {
//state = { visible: false };

/*showDrawer = () => {
  this.setState({
    visible: true,
  });
 };

onClose = () => {
  this.setState({
    visible: false,
  });
};*/

 render() {
  return (
      <Drawer
        title="Event Details"
        placement="right"
        closable={false}
        onClose={this.onClose}
        visible={this.props.showDrawer}
       >
        <p></p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
       </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

export default EventDetailsDrawer
```

Thanks for your answer and our help

Comment: @Think-Twice thanks for your answer. Could you give me please an example, which i can use in my project? That would be very helpfully for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HomePageContent:

```
<EventDetailsDrawer 
    showDrawer={this.state.showDrawer}
    title = {item.title}
    handleClick = {this.handleClick}
/>
```

EventDetailsDrawer

```
<Drawer
    title="Event Details"
    placement="right"
    closable={false}
    onClose={this.props.handleClick}
    visible={this.props.showDrawer}
>
    <p></p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
</Drawer>
```

there are method pass as props. remove second `<EventDetailsDrawer />`

Comment: thanks, now i can close the drawer. When i click on a EventCard, i want to pass the title to the Drawer. I use the title-prop (item.title) for this. But no matter which card I click, it will always show me title 6 in the drawer. (Title 6 is the last entry in my data array, by the way). How can i solve this?

Comment: all time open all drawer here 6 one last open drawer show that is reason.  you try 6 state or one array state use for this example. neither there open all the drawer  here. `showDrawer={this.state.showDrawer}` is same state using

Comment: could you give me please an example, how can i solve the issue and how can use it in my project? It would be very helpfully for me, thanks a lot

Comment: can you provide working example for this or wait i will build example 4 hours later, I am busy now

Comment: thanks a lot, if you still need an working example, just let me know...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179948/discussion-between-thilina-sampath-and-niklas).